# ThreadPool C#, result of worker item is too slow, why?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, forms, threadpool

I don't know if I am doing something wrong, I am using SmartThreadPool to manage my threads. On this particular case I am calling an instance of SmartThreadPool and then getting the result of the worker item (method to send email). The 'String result' receives the output of the method. If it is OK it shows OK, otherwise is shows the exception.

```
SmartThreadPool smartThreadPool = new SmartThreadPool();

String result = (String)smartThreadPool.QueueWorkItem(x => emailHelper.sendEmail(whichMail.Text, emailTo.Text, subject.Text, bodyMsg.Text)).Result;

if (result != "True")
    helper.showMessageBox(Properties.Resources.emailNotSent + result, "x");

else
    aux.setRadDesktop(Properties.Resources.emailSent, "", false);
```

Problem is when i am casting the result to String it is TOO SLOW and even my UI is suspended for like 2 seconds, i don't know why. If i ignore the worker item result by doing this:

```
smartThreadPool.QueueWorkItem(x => emailHelper.sendEmail(whichMail.Text, emailTo.Text, subject.Text, bodyMsg.Text));
```

Everything works fine, any clues?

Comment: Your smart threadpool is not that smart.  It allows you to wait for the TP result.  That's not exactly a great feature, sending an email can easily take several seconds.  There's just no point left in running it on a thread, might as well call the method directly.  You can never make that mistake with the .NET ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() method.  Throw away that SmartThreadPool class, it is getting you into trouble.

Comment: @HansPassant Does the same apply to `Task`?

Comment: @HansPassant: I agree with your comment in general; but to be fair to the OP, the TPL `Task<TResult>` class has a similar `Result` property that produces exactly the same behaviour if accessed from the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a nested thread, it works flawlesly. Thanks you all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in casting to string, but in using `Result` property that waits for your work item to complete before returning a value.